# APNS Openssl Connection from PHP for Apple Push Notification?

Tags: php, ios, openssl, apple-push-notifications

Finally i have sent a notification from my local server to my device. I followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2 and many of the peoples from stack overflow helped me to reach this. I Thank you all my friends.

I have one doubt on the server setup. For my local use i have used `MAMP for Apache and MySQL servers`. Finally `i open the ssl from Terminal used certificate.pem and key.pem`. Is there any way to `open ssl from php script`. But, i don't know any single script of php because i am ios developer. Sorry for this.

Yesterday i have used below commands in my Terminal to open ssl and connect to APNS,

```
unknownc42c032e8297:~ gopi$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php /Users/gopi/Desktop/PushChatServer/push/push.php development
unknownc42c032e8297:~ gopi$ cd /Users/gopi/Desktop/PushChatServer/push
unknownc42c032e8297:push gopi$ telnet gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com 2195
Trying 17.149.34.66...
Connected to gateway.sandbox.push-apple.com.akadns.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
unknownc42c032e8297:push **gopi$ openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert gopiAPNCert.pem -key gopiAPNKey.pem**
Enter pass phrase for gopiAPNKey.pem:
CONNECTED(00000003)
.
.
.
.
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
creagx
closed

unknownc42c032e8297:push gopi$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php /Users/gopi/Desktop/PushChatServer/push/push.php development
^C
```

Is there any way to openssl from our php file? It is possible or Terminal usage is better and is the only way for this? Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read his Part 1 & download the full source code from Part 2 to start with.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Thanks. I have followed both two parts. I have used command prompt (Terminal) for openssl. I need is there any way to use openssl from our php file. Can you please help me for this scenario? Thanks.

Comment: His source codes already illustrated the methods . See `SimplePush.php`

Comment: I can understand what you are tell Mr.Shivan Raptor. But, i have used the above Terminal code to open SSL. If want to know about that i will post that Terminal code in my question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: noted that. please read my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post the Terminal output from a command to PHP , you can use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) , [system()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [passthru()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php). The usage is slightly different among these functions, but they basically do the same job.