# SSL/TLS alert when connecting to gateway.sandbox.push.apple

Tags: php, iphone, openssl, apple-push-notifications

When running the code

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert ECert.pem -key EKey.pem
```

I get the error

```
5155:error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1102:SSL alert number 46
5155:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:182:
```

I have tried to start over and get the certificate and I have tried to get the private key again but if anyone can give me advise on how to fix this would be great.

Comment: Also see [APNS sandbox Connection failed error '0' in php file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10585283/608639) and [APNS Openssl Connection from PHP for Apple Push Notification?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10595481/608639)

Answer (score 1):

Alert 46 is `certificate_unknown` (from [RFC 5246, Section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246)). It means:

> Some other (unspecified) issue arose in processing the certificate, rendering it unacceptable.

The client credentials/certificate you are providing is rejected by Apple.

Also see [SSL Mutual authentication Fails](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/61578) on the Information Security Stack Exchange.

---

> how to fix this would be great.

It looks like you generated your own credentials. You should supply credentials accepted by Apple.

I think one of the goals of the Apple developer programs is to provide you with an acceptable identity (others include recurring revenue streams). Under the developer program, Apple will validate a signing request and issue you a certificate for these sorts of things.

In case you are wondering, I don't think you can avoid the Apple developer program in this case. (And for what its worth, I generally don't agree with the developer program requirement, and charging me $200 a year to use my iOS devices and MacBook).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add -verbose.

What this firstly tells you is that the root CA which has signed the CA that signed the CA that signed gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com is not in the default openSSL bundle.

In the above case that is the cert for:

```
i:/O=Entrust.net/OU=www.entrust.net/CPS_2048 incorp. by ref. (limits liab.)/OU=(c) 1999 Entrust.net Limited/CN=Entrust.net Certification Authority (2048)
```

Which you can fetch from http://www.entrust.net/knowledge-base/technote.cfm?tn=8412 and can add to above command with -CAfile*.

Once that is do you should be able to make a proper connection and get at least an OK on the server cert:

```
 Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Dw.

*: you can also cheat - just add -showcert; which gives you the cert of the server; cut and paste that into a server-cert.pem and add '-CAfile server-cert.pem' and openssl won't verify it any further up the tree.

Comment: Now I get the error 

`CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 /C=US/O=Entrust, Inc./OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference/OU=(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc./CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
19100:error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:1102:SSL alert number 46
19100:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-44/src/ssl/s23_lib.c:182:`

Comment: Certificate was corrupt. Just changed the cer file with a new one and it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: @BigT - you should provide an answer and accept it so others can quickly locate it. Do you know how the certificate got corrupted?